# Is there any HandShake mechanism for GIT:// protocol?

Tags: git, network-protocols

Is there any **HandShake**(the connection open) mechanism when using `GIT://` protocol?

Just like SSh, HTTPS and...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the section [The Git Protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol) in **Chapter 4 : Git on the Server - The Protocols** from the book **ProGit** by *Scott Chacon* :

> Next is the Git protocol. This is a special daemon that comes packaged with Git; it listens on a dedicated port (9418) that provides a service similar to the SSH protocol, but with absolutely no authentication.

This protocol has no authentication. This means that there is no need to the handshake to keep the connection open. Basically, this protocol is used as read-only for cloning and pulling from repositories.